# sending each looped pandas calculation to a different thread (python3.6.5) with pool.map

Tags: python, pandas, loops, multiprocessing, threadpool

with a basic pandas df of financial market OHLCV data, I am trying to add numerous calculated columns to the df. The large number of columns and calculations is making this SLOW SLOW SLOW! 
Trying to multiprocess with pool.map, but getting nowhere. 
Ideally, each iteration of the loop should be sent to a discrete thread. Simplified moving averages in code below.
Shown simple dictionary and rolling mean works SLOWLY
TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'
All help appreciated-thx

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

#####################################################
# DJIA_OHLCV_test.csv has format:
# Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
# 
1/2/2015,17823.07031,17951.7793,17731.30078,17832.99023,17832.99023,76270000
# 
1/3/2015,17823.07031,17951.7793,17731.30078,17832.99023,17832.99023,76270000
DJIA = pd.read_csv('DJIA_OHLCV_test.csv')
"""
#####################################################
# # This works! please comment out to switch 
# MAdict = {'MA50':50, 'MA100':100, 'MA200':200} # Define Moving Average 
Windows

# for MAkey in MAdict:
#     DJIA[('ma' + MAkey)] = pd.Series.rolling(DJIA['Adj Close'], 
              window=MAdict[MAkey]).mean()

#####################################################
"""
# This doesn't work! please comment out to switch 
MAdict = {'MA50':50, 'MA100':100, 'MA200':200}
pool = ThreadPool(3)

def moving_average(MAkey):
    return pd.Series.rolling(DJIA['Adj Close'], window=MAdict[MAkey]).mean()

for MAkey in MAdict:
    DJIA[('ma' + MAkey)] = pool.map(moving_average(MAkey))

#####################################################
print(DJIA.tail())
```

Comment: Minor edit to naming of dataframe moving average columns working code:         DJIA[('ma' + str(MAdict[MAkey]))] = pd.Series.rolling(DJIA['Adj Close'], window=MAdict[MAkey]).mean()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pool.map` is a blocking call, so instead of iterating over `MAdict` and calling `pool.map` you need to pass the iterable directly as an argument to `pool.map`:

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool


def moving_average(ma):
    return pd.Series.rolling(djia['Adj Close'], window=ma).mean()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    N_WORKERS = 3
    MA_DICT = {'MA50':50, 'MA100':100, 'MA200':200}

    djia = pd.read_csv('DJIA_OHLCV_test.csv')

    with Pool(N_WORKERS) as pool:
        results = pool.map(moving_average, iterable=MA_DICT.values())

    # concatenate results and rename columns
    results = pd.concat(results, axis=1)
    results.columns = ['ma' + key for key in MA_DICT]

    djia = pd.concat([djia, results], axis=1)

    print(djia.tail())
```

Comment: Nice-Thanks! I see how it is done. Unfortunately the speed gains between the for-loop method and the worker thread method did not happen. Surprisingly(for me! a 'newpy'), for an +8000 entry dataframe, calculating 23 new columns of data, the for-loop method took 0.06s and the worker-thread method took 0.18 seconds.

Comment: Nice-Thanks! I see how it is done. Unfortunately the speed gains between the for-loop method and the worker-thread method did not happen (as I have implemented). Surprisingly(for me! a 'newpy'), for an +8000 row dataframe, calculating 23 new columns of data, the for-loop method took 0.06s and the worker-thread method took 0.18 seconds. My real test will be to apply the worker-thread method to plotting the multiple dataseries via multiple threads which I will attempt when I get to it. But your solution perfectly shows the code structure I need on a simple example. thx

Comment: @MarkD You're welcome! I already wondered how this calculation on daily data can be SLOW, SLOW, SLOW ;) 8000 rows is really way to little to earn the overhead of creating a pool back in the first place.